# How do i get a hedge to thicken and fill out?

Tags: shrubs

The lower part of the hedge is thin and bare, ie bare branches. The top is flourishing with new growth.

Comment: Hi Chris, a picture that shows what plant the hedge is made of would help and your location.

Comment: If a hedge is only pruned at the top, essentially all growth will be at the top. Sounds like improper pruning.

Answer (score 1):

At the level of detail provided in the question:

Narrow the top so the bottom gets sunlight.

However, depending on the plant, that may be "too little, too late" to actually bring back where branches have died back to the trunk, in which case the answer is to replace with new plants and keep them trimmed "narrow on the top" to keep them in active growth on the bottom.

Hedges which are vertical or spread outwards on the top do tend to die out on the bottom, primarily due to lack of light.

Comment: Yes, two basic principles: 1) hedges get denser if they are pruned frequently; 2) hedges die off at the bottom if they aren't significantly wider at the bottom than at the top.

Answer (score 0):

I was wondering if you have tried epsom salt on or around your hedges? With pruning it regularly, this could be a sufficient filling for your shrubs!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).